# Cannot copy and paste Korean text from a PDF file compiled with Latex

Tags: unicode

I have prepared a document in Korean language using Latex. The PDF file looks really good, but when ever I copied a text from that PDF file and paste it to another application such as note pad, it shows some rubbish. It happens with both "kotex" and "CJKutf8" packages.

Using "kotex" package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kotex}
\begin{document}
안녕하세요!
\end{document}
```

Using "CJKutf8" package

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document} 
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{}
 \CJKfamily{mj}
 전체 문서에 대한 기본 정보를 소개 단락. 
 \begin{verbatim}
 그것은 간격 방법을 참조 그대로 글꼴을 테스트
 \end{verbatim}
\end{CJK} 
Latin characters are also allowed.
\end{document}
```

[image: PDF file.]

[image: Copy and paste text from the pdf file]

Comment: I get a better result but it isn't perfect either. Imho if you want good copy & paste you should switch to xelatex/lualatex and use fontspec and a unicode font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to use **XeLaTeX** or **LuaLaTeX** for writing Chinese/Japanese/Korean document.
An example than can be compiled by `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans CJK JP} 
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Chinese 中文
  \item Japanese 日本語 にほんご
  \item Korean 한국어
  \item English
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I use [Google Note](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) CJK fonts as it's a nice font for Chinese, Japanese and Korean.

To better control the spacing, you need a package for CJK language.
An example than can be compiled by `xelatex`, using `xeCJK` package:

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK JP}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans CJK JP}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Chinese 中文
  \item Japanese 日本語 にほんご
  \item Korean 한국어
  \item English
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```